# Ngx Translate Inner HTML tags in html

Tags: angular, innerhtml, ngx-translate

I am using `ngx-translate` lib to support I18N in my angular app. Can anyone help me to translate inner HTML with multiple tags?? It only keeps the `class` tag and avoid the rest of them.

**i18n/en.json**

```
 "CONTENT": "<h5 class='subsection-header' id='cont-1'>Events and characters</h5>"
```

**info.component.html**

```
<div class="section" [innerHtml]="'CONTENT' | translate"></div>
```

**Result:**

```
<h5 class="subsection-header">Events and characters</h5> // Not applying ID tag.
```

Comment: Why would you store your html in translation, that is bad practice?

Comment: Because it's the info page with lot of text with different style... so I can handle it in just one key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a function that will return the innerHTML, while returning the value use DomSanitizer function bypassSecurityTrustHtml()
example :

ts :

```
 import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    
    function() {
    let content: string; // content used in translate
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="section" [innerHtml]="function()"></div>
```

that will keep the id tag and prevent the default behavior of innerHTML tag

Answer (score 0):

You can create a safeHtml pipe for your trusted HTML to be reused in your application

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Use it

```
   <div class="section" [innerHtml]="'CONTENT' | translate | safeHtml"></div>
```